# Deferred loading in Entity Framework using DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'am really confused about this issue that I've been facing using the deferred loading features of entity framework.
I know the extensions that trigger the database query like .ToList(), .Count(), etc.
My question is, if you are using IEnumerable DTO as return type, will this trigger the database query?

Example you have the following DTO:

```
public DtoUser
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this method on your business layer:

```
public BLLUser
{
   public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUser
   {
      var output = from u in context.User
                   select new DtoUser
                   {
                      Name = u.Name,
                      Age = u.Age
                   };
   }
}
```

And I will call it as:

```
private void GetUserOnBll()
{
    using (BLLUser b = new BLLUser())
    {
       var dtoUser = b.GetAllUser();

       // can I still do this without triggering the database query
       // or the query is already been triggered
       // since the return type is an IEnumerable DTO
       var filtered = dtoUser.Where(n => n.Name == "TEST");
    }
}
```

will the "b.GetUser()" method will trigger the database query or do I have to use the .ToList() for it to trigger the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b.GetUser() will NOT trigger db query, and NEITHER `dtoUser.Where(n => n.Name == "TEST")` will  trigger query. The differed Execution means it will execute db query only when you "use" it, for example a foreach clause, or SingleOrDefault()/Count()/...

So your program above will do what you want. But there'll be performance issue. The generated SQL will like 
`Select Name, Age from User`
It will get all records from database into memory, do a filtering in memory then return the filtered records. If you want the filtering in database side, should replace IEnumerable with IQueryable

Comment: Hi, Teddy, your explanation's really great! It helps clear all the clouds inside my head! Just a follow up, is this a rule of thumb that using IEnumerable as a return type will retrieve all the record first before filtering?

Comment: @arvstracthoughts Not always "all" records, depends on your code. We can say, all filtering condition AFTER ASEnumberable() will not be applied in database side. For example: context.User.Take(10).AsEnumberable().Take(2); ==> Will retrieve top 10 records from database into memory, then return top 2.

Answer (score 0):

Create a proeprty of  List of DtoUser List

and assign the value by calling your function in constructor. let me know if you need sample code.

another thing I don't know how you call and get the context i recommend to use IQueryable rather than IEnumerable because IQueryable handle in database and IEnumerable handle on your server memory.

regards
Pubudu